# Unable to Open my App in other Devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debugging

My Application runs `finely when i run`..but it does not open on Some other Android devices..Here i include my `screenshots + Android Manifest`..please help me..

Screenshot

[image]

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ajay.com.mydict">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ListActi">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OnlyDes" />
        <activity android:name=".BothLay" />
        <activity android:name=".Listing" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest ready please check your settings here==> build.gradle(Module:app)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "www.appcodeinfotech.com"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i Edited my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ajay.com.mydict">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ListActi">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OnlyDes" />
        <activity android:name=".BothLay" />
        <activity android:name=".Listing" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I thought  should be used for hide Actionbar name while Text Selection..but it does not works..So i removed the line..and it works..Sorry,before trying i posted it in here..